# Chrome extension: Highlighting text in an input box

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, highlight

I'm working on a Google Chrome Extension which involves finding text in a page, much like Chromes Ctrl+F find feature. One of the things I need to do is highlight text in an input box that matches a regular expression.

I've looked for advice on how to highlight specific strings but the only methods I've found suggested have been selecting text or inserting HTML and CSS to style the text.
This latter method however does not work within text boxes and can break seriously mess up a page.

The fact that the find feature works and is able to highlight any selectable text indicates to me that there must be a way of doing this, but I'm not sure how to find it.

Can anyone advise me on this?

Comment: The `find` feature highlights the text in the renderer, not in DOM.

Comment: Does that mean that I won't be able to replicate the method?

Comment: Yep, this is an internally rendered color overlay, the API is not exposed.